# Html javascript row instead of col

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script, but i'd like to be able to display 2 rows / 7 cols instead of 7 rows / 2 cols.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var date = new Date(); // today
    var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [48.23, 4.28], 2);
    var list = ['Fajr', 'Sunrise', 'Dhuhr', 'Asr', 'Maghrib', 'Isha'];
    var html = '<table id="timetable">';
    html += '<tr><td colspan="7">'+ date.toLocaleDateString()+ '</td></tr>';
    for(var i in list)  {
        html += '<tr><td>'+ list[i]+ '</td>';
        html += '<td>'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+ '</td></tr>';
    }
    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution

2 rows with the first row showing `list[i]` and the second row showing `times[list[i].toLowerCase()]`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var date = new Date(); // today
    var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [48.23, 4.28], 2);
    var list = ['Fajr', 'Sunrise', 'Dhuhr', 'Asr', 'Maghrib', 'Isha'];
    var html = '<table id="timetable">';
    html += '<tr><td colspan="7">'+ date.toLocaleDateString()+ '</td></tr>';
    html += '<tr>';
    for(var i in list)  {
        html += '<td>'+ list[i]+ '</td>';
    }
    html += '</tr>';

    html += '<tr>';
    for(var i in list)  {
        html += '<td>'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+ '</td>';
    }
    html += '</tr>';

    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use separate loops to create each row, first iterating and printing the items from the list, then the corresponding times.

```
var date = new Date(); // today
var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [48.23, 4.28], 2);
var list = ['Fajr', 'Sunrise', 'Dhuhr', 'Asr', 'Maghrib', 'Isha'];
var html = '<table id="timetable">';
html += '<tr><td colspan="7">'+ date.toLocaleDateString()+ '</td></tr>';
html += '<tr>';
for(var i in list)  {
    html += '<td>'+ list[i]+ '</td>';
}
html += "</tr>";
html += "<tr>";
for (var i in list) {
    html += '<td>'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+ '</td></tr>';
}
html += '</tr></table>';
document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;
```